# Pagination on 10k migrated questions is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, migrated-questions

I was poking at the oldest of the migrated questions to see what they look like the other day (should they be closed? are they a stub of an answer after a rejected migration?)

Today, I can't do any pagination on it.

I start out at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=

[image: first page]

I click 'next' - same page.

[image: "second" page]

I click '73' - same page.

[image: page "73"]

Comment: Also repro on IE11

Comment: Reproduced on Stack Overflow (using Firefox 25.0.01). Neither the `next` or the individual page buttons work.

Comment: You have to click on the `here` or `away` first after clikcing the Migrated tab and then pagination works.

Comment: @rene *interesting* - that works... there's still a bug lurking in there somewhere then.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the navigation and page buttons build the url based on the current window.location. By clicking the here button the url becomes /migrated/here and then page query parameter makes sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next build, thanks for the report.

Comment: We don't get to know what was wrong with it?

Comment: @UndotheSnowman localization bug, someone didn't know the links needed to be different *before* you click here/away up top for that question list, so a needed case was dropped

Comment: (cc @UndotheSnowman) Localization. It's always localization...

Comment: It looks like its fixed now.  Thank you.